# В приведённом предложении (см.) есть деепричастный оборот? Нужно ли его обособлять?

Tags: деепричастия

***Невзирая на холодную погоду Маша пошла гулять в лёгком платье.***

Comment: Здесь нет деепричастного оборота. Здесь единственный оборот —  _невзирая на холодную погоду_. Он не деепричастный, но обстоятельственный, присоединяется отглагольным предлогом НЕВЗИРАЯ НА. Похож на деепричастный, но он не деепричастный.

Answer (score 1):

[Согласно параграфу 75 полного академического справочника «Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации» под ред. В. В. Лопатина (М., 2006 и след.), обстоятельственные обороты, имеющие в своем составе производные предлоги и предложные сочетания (*благодаря, вопреки, ввиду, в целях, в связи с, во избежание, вследствие, по случаю, по причине, при наличии, согласно с, в отличие от, в противоположность, наподобие, при условии, в силу, за отсутствием, несмотря на, **невзирая на**, спустя, независимо от* и др.), **обособляются при подчеркивании их смысла**.](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=310857)

В приведённом предложении нет ни деепричастия, ни деепричастного оборота.

[**невзирая на**, *предлог*](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0&all=x)

Вы вольны как поставить, так и проигнорировать запятую.

*Невзирая на холодную погоду Маша пошла гулять в лёгком платье.*

*Невзирая на холодную погоду, Маша пошла гулять в лёгком платье.*

---

> текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом, -

причастный оборот, однако это и есть тот текст?

Comment: Согласен по поводу деепричастного оборота — его нет. А по поводу _текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом_, думаю, ошибка и автор хотел выделить центральный текст жирным, но в итоге рядом поставил фразу: _текст, выделенный жирным шрифром_.

Comment: Максимка, так нужны тебе мои ответы – без ссылок на какие-либо пункты и своды правил? Я нисколько не педагог и все правила перезабыла. Но у меня 35-летний стаж работы со словом.